# New Request object has no body in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, request, fetch

I want to manually create a Request object before sending it, and when I do that in FireFox v118.0.2 (current, as of writing) the Request object I get back has no body...

The demo code below behaves this way in these browsers:

- Chrome: works
- Edge: works
- Safari: works
- Firefox: error <---

```js
(() => {
  const request = new Request("/api/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: "John Wick", password: "P@ssw0rd!" }),
  });
  if (!request.body) {
    return alert("Error: request.body is missing");
  }
  alert(`Success! request has body!`);
})();
```

^ Please, copy/paste the above snippet into FF and see if it works!^
*Note: I intentionally wrapped it in an IIFE so you can copy/paste/modify as much as you want.*

If I send the same data as a fetch, the body is present in the network request tab.

```js
fetch("/api/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: "John Wick", password: "P@ssw0rd!" }),
});
```

So this is very annoying and not very clear why. I've read [MDN Request Constructor Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) and done a few Google searches but I can't find anything.

Thanks for looking!

*Edit:* MDN is actually reporting that this is not supported in FF... [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/body#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Seems like your edit should have been [an answer](/help/self-answer)

Comment: :| yes, you're right. Thanks B

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as this feature is just not supported in FireFox right now.
[MDN Docs Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/body#browser_compatibility)

2nd best option for me was to call request.arrayBuffer() as a fallback if the body property does not exist.